# Change the ("Yes") button label on a Windows.Forms Dialog

Tags: c#, winforms

Until now I used a dialog like this:

```
dialogResult = 
       System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(
                                    Strings.MyString,
                                    Strings.MyTitle,
                                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
```

Now, I've been asked to use "Refresh" & "Cancel" buttons instead of "Yes" / "No".

Can I make the "Yes" button show "Refresh" label?

Comment: Design your own dialog.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18399/Localizing-System-MessageBox

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not. You will need to create your own custom dialog and style it according to your requirements.

Comment: Actually it is possible, see my comment above.